# Escaping content for placement with jQuery's .html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, html-entities

I need to accept arbitrary user input. Later, I want to copy that input, already escaped to HTML entities, into a textarea so it can be edited. However, jQuery's `jQuery.html()` function reads out the HTML entities as if they were real HTML and injects the user script directly into the page. I need to grab the contents of the user input, even if it contains `<script>` tags, and output to a textarea where it can be edited.

So, I need this:

```
<textarea name="empty"></textarea>
<div name="user-input"> &lt;script&gt; window.alert('hi'); &lt;/script&gt; </div>
```

to become this:

```
<textarea name="empty"> &lt;script&gt; window.alert('hi'); &lt;/script&gt; </textarea>
<div name="user-input"> &lt;script&gt; window.alert('hi'); &lt;/script&gt; </div>
```

on JavaScript trigger. Instead, the textarea becomes:

```
<textarea name="empty"> <script> window.alert('hi'); </script> </textarea>
```

displaying an empty text box and injecting the user's JavaScript into the page.

Right now I am getting the contents of user-input and placing them into the textarea like so:

```
 $('#edit-textarea').html(($('#user-input').text()));
```

I've tried several variations of this to no avail.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/vkRkt/8 for a test case.

EDIT:

See discussion below. The solution in my case was to use `jquery.val()` instead of `jquery.html()`. I skipped over val because I was under the impression that it was an alias for `jquery.attr('value', new_value)`, which has its own injection issues (can be stopped with a "). **`val()` is not the same as `attr('value', val)`** and appears safe from injection attempts in my brief testing.

If anyone runs across this later and knows that `val` is actually not a safe way to do this, please answer and update us immediately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#edit-textarea').val(($('#user-input').text()));
```

works fine for me. I also tried using `.text()` instead of `.val()` and it of course kept the escaping as well. Don't use `.html()` if you don't want the data to be HTML.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkRkt/9/)

Comment: I was previously adjusting value, but that's not really the correct place to modify textarea contents, *and* my quotes are not escaped aforehand so a simple " allows the user to inject. I was hoping to avoid that; by using html(), I just want to fill in the area between <textarea> and </textarea>

Comment: Interesting, on further consideration it appears that val() sets the value as a JavaScript property. I had believed that it was just a shortcut for `attr('value', new_value)`, so perhaps that will work. Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: The HTML is just the starting position. From then on, everything happens in the DOM.